# Error with STR_TO_DATE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Currently, my `enrollment_date` is a string variable in the format
*02JUN2015*

I'm using the following code to change that into the correct date format of mysql.

```
Update table_name 
SET enrollment_date = (Select STR_TO_DATE(enrollment_date, '%d%M%Y');
```

However, I'm getting the following message.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

The inner function works fine, but I don't know what part of the syntax is wrong.

I'd apprecaite any tips!

Comment: You don't need the SELECT. `UPDATE table_name SET enrollment_date = STR_TO_DATE(enrollment_date, '%d%M%Y')` will work (presuming STR_TO_DATE accepts that format).

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket:

```
Update table_name 
SET enrollment_date = (Select STR_TO_DATE(enrollment_date, '%d%M%Y'));
```

You needed an extra bracket just before the semi-colon.